# Shiro with Springboot integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have integrated Apache Shiro with Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. The Spring Boot project is in [this](https://github.com/yunus89/spring-boot-javafx-jpa-shiro-demo.git) GitHub repo.

The problem is when I run and try to authenticate the app I get the following error

```
roleAdmin.getId() 1: null
roleAdmin.getId() 2: 3
Current user is not authenticated.
2016-08-13 09:49:45.715  WARN 10528 --- [lication Thread]  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2016-08-13 09:49:45.716 ERROR 10528 --- [lication Thread] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - yunus, rememberMe=false].   Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
```

It completely fails to authenticate, I managed to create [this](https://github.com/yunus89/spring-boot-javafx-jpa-shiro-demo.git) repo to elaborate my problem. Check it out.

Solutions and criticism are highly acceptable.

## Update

If any extra info is needed to clarify my question, just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is indicative of the problem, which lies in your User repository's `@Query` definition:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.username FROM users u WHERE u.username = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
User findByUsername(String username);
```

As you can see, you're selecting only the username, instead of selecting every column. Since you're using Spring Data JPA, you don't really need the `@Query` at all, it's enough to just say:

```
User findByUsername(String username);
```

Your other problem, however, is how you compare the passwords in your custom realm. The password coming from the DB will be encrypted, meaning that you cannot just say

```
user.getPassword().equals(new String(upat.getPassword()))
```

You'll have to compare the passwords using the `DefaultPasswordService` by calling its `passwordsMatch` method and, since you'e just verified the paswords yourself, you should use `AllowAllCredentialsMatcher` in your realm:

```
public class CustomSecurityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Autowired
    private UserManagerService userManager;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultPasswordService passwordService;

    public CustomSecurityRealm() {
        this(new AllowAllCredentialsMatcher());
    }

    public CustomSecurityRealm(final CredentialsMatcher matcher) {
        super(matcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        // remains the same
    }

     @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upat = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        User user = userManager.findByUsername(upat.getUsername());                             
        if(user != null && passwordService.passwordsMatch(upat.getPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
            return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword(), getName());
        }
        else {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid username/password combination!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now, thanks to you. This problem has been holding me for loooong.

Comment: Awesome! Btw, you posting the runnable example helped a lot, it took around 5 minutes to track down the issue, if only more people would do that :)